# Salesforce Lightning - Reply, Reply All From Custom Email Related List Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, email, service-cloud-console

We have custom requirement where we need to build custom email related list similar to standard. please see below screenshot - 
[image]

Question - How can we use standard "**Reply**" and "**Reply All**" feature of salesforce in my custom lightning related list component ?

Comment: What have you tried to do? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: My Question is - Can i use reply all and reply functionality of salesforce email related list in lightning component ?